# Three.js + Blender + ColladaLoader: undefined "geometry" and "material" (r71)

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm loading .dae scene (from Blender) with:

```
var collada_loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    collada_loader.load(
        "resources/3D/objs.dae",
        function(collada)
        {
            obj1 = collada.scene.getChildByName("obj1", true);
            obj1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            obj1.material.color.setHex(0x003388);
            scene.add(obj1);

            obj2 = collada.scene.getChildByName("obj2", true);
            obj2.position.set(100, 100, 100);
            obj2.material.color.setHex(0x003388);
            scene.add(obj2);

            obj3 = collada.scene.getChildByName("obj3", true);
            obj3.position.set(-100, -100, -100);
            obj3.material.color.setHex(0x003388);
            scene.add(obj3);

        }
    );
```

but obj*.material and obj*.geometry properties are undefined! Why? 
I found the materials in loader's object and tried to create mesh:

```
var collada_loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    collada_loader.load(
        "resources/3D/objs.dae",
        function(collada)
        {
            var obj1_mat = collada.dae.materials["obj1_mat-material"];
            var obj1_geom = collada.dae.geometries["obj1_geom-mesh"];
            obj1 = new THREE.Mesh(obj1_geom, obj1_mat);
            obj1.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            obj1.material.color.setHex(0x003388);
            scene.add(obj1);

            var obj2_mat = collada.dae.materials["obj2_mat-material"];
            var obj2_geom = collada.dae.geometries["obj2_geom-mesh"];
            obj2 = new THREE.Mesh(obj2_geom, obj2_mat);
            obj2.position.set(100, 100, 100);
            obj2.material.color.setHex(0x003388);
            scene.add(obj2);

            var obj3_mat = collada.dae.materials["obj3_mat-material"];
            var obj3_geom = collada.dae.geometries["obj3_geom-mesh"];
            obj3 = new THREE.Mesh(obj3_geom, obj3_mat);
            obj3.position.set(-100, -100, -100);
            obj3.material.color.setHex(0x003388);
            scene.add(obj3);

        }
    );
```

but now Chrome writes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: geometry.addEventListener is not a function three.js:21479
```

WTF?
I solved this problem! There is THREE.ColladaLoader2() - it works fine!

Comment: And when I use OBJMTLLoader properties are undefined.

Comment: Hey, guys! I solved this problem... This is problem in r71 build... I connected https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r65/three.min.js from cdn and Collada loader from r59! And it works now!